# Auto-Update Office for Mac using Apple Remote Desktop

Tags: mac, remote-desktop, microsoft-office

We have approximately 20 Mac desktops in a Windows Server 2008 environment - that are managed with Apple Remote Desktop. These desktops have a variety of Office for Mac installations - Office 2008, Office 2011, and running at various patch levels.

I'd like to use Apple Remote Desktop for triggering of updates. Has anyone done this before with any success? Microsoft's recommendation seems to be to package the updates into a disk image and manually install them, obviously it would be preferable to automate this and not have to touch every machine...

Answer (score 0):

Certainly ARD v3 can do ths with ease, have you a more specific question?

Comment: Thought I was being pretty specific: I want to remotely start Microsoft Auto-Update and allow it to patch itself from the internet. How is this accomplished "with ease?"

Comment: Can't you just start Microsoft auto-update?

Comment: Unfortunately, it requires end-user interaction - I've spent a couple hours looking for a command line instruction, to no avail.